# Want to install Unity in Lubuntu 16.04. Guide me please

Tags: unity, lubuntu, desktop-environments

I installed Lubuntu 16.04 by default because my computer system is old. I also want to try out unity in it. How should I do it? Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Please **do not do that**. If you want to test another desktop environment, do it in another system, either live, persistent live or installed alongside the current one. Do not tamper with your main operating system, because it is almost impossible to undo it. If you find that Unity is too slow and want to remove it, you will probably damage the LXDE of Lubuntu. See this link and links from it, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: @sudodus - Installing multiple WM/DE does no harm other then crowding the menu and taking disk space.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think that if the OP wants to remove one of them (in this case probably Unity), there will be problems. -- But if you want me to remove the comment, just tell me, and I'll do it.

Comment: @sudodus Perhaps, but nowhere in the question does the OP mention removing anything, they only mention "Want to install Unity ... " and "want to try out unity ... ". Perhaps ask for clarification as you correctly point out removing DE is not easy in Ubuntu.

Comment: Manik Rastogi, If you find that Unity will be too slow, would you accept, that you have to keep it? In this case, by all means, install it into Lubuntu. Otherwise, if you want to be able to remove it, then you should test in another system, as I tried to explain in my first comment.

Comment: @sudodus I hate Unity! But if Manik Rastogi installs it over Lubuntu, he can select if he logs in Unity or Lubuntu at the log-in screen. If log-in screen is disabled, he can log-out (not shut-down) and then select the prefered Desktop Enviroment. But crowding the menu and taking disk space is not avoidable, exept if he manages to uninstall Unity without destroying the hole system. I would suggest to Manik Rastogi to stay away of Unity. I tried Unity at 11.04 and I have not touched it again since now. Even if I wanted a fancy and touch-screen-like desktop, I would choose Gnome 3.

Comment: But with both DEs you would have to do more clicks to open a program, sometimes you have to type the first letters of the programs, if you are a keyboard/menu-navigation user I belive you won't like it. Also I think Unity installs _zeitgeist_ by default, I am not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Just execute in the terminal

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or just visit this address

[Software Center - Ubuntu Desktop](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-desktop)

If you get any error try this command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

and try again.